# In Ruby on Rails is there a way to view the properties of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, netbeans, netbeans6.7

I am using NetBeans to create my first Ruby on Rails application. Is there a way by which I can view all of the properties of a model? Should I just be looking in the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just use `db/schema.rb` - seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [annotate](http://github.com/ctran/annotate_models) gem for this - it will add comments to the top of each model indicating its properties.

Answer (score 4):

You could call `Model.attributes` in Rails' console. This gives a hash with all attributes.

Be careful when using this inside your real code as it always recreates the hash and is therefore pretty expensive.

Answer (score 4):

Just type your model name on the rails console then press Enter.

```
rails c # start your rails console

User

=> User(id: integer, email: string, password_digest: string...)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is viewing this and is using a newer version of Rails, you can just call `Model` in the console. (I'm on Rails 3.2.1 and Ruby 1.9.2p290.)

In fact, calling `Model.attributes` in this case does not work.

Answer (score 0):

A nice little tool that I use is from MySQL. It is called [MySQL Administrator](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html).

It lets me validate that the db (development/test/production), the tables for the db, and finally the columns(attributes).

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.attributes #=> {'name' => 'foo', 'desc' => 'bar'}
```

P.S. www.railsbrain.com - use this.